# 500 Internal Server Error while using httppost and sending multipart form data

Tags: android, http-post, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I am sending multipart form data to my server but it gives Internal Server error. The same request gives a successful response in postman but it throws internal server error when I do it in android. Can someone help me? Thanks.
Below is my code

```
 private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xxx.xx/xx");


            httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "xxxx.xxxx.xxx");

            try {
                FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()
                        + "/Camera/image.jpg"));


                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("image", bin);
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                System.out.println("Requesting : " + httppost.getRequestLine());
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

My Logcat

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:76)
org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:63)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:802)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:772)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:761)
com.sukshi.reliancetest.MainActivity$UpdateTask$override.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
com.sukshi.reliancetest.MainActivity$UpdateTask$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
com.sukshi.reliancetest.MainActivity$UpdateTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:0)
com.sukshi.reliancetest.MainActivity$UpdateTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: check you server log

Comment: How did you know that it's giving 500 error? Give some clue to us, post your logcat

Comment: @Toaster Please have a look at my logcat

Comment: Really complicated stuff. The 500 error can happen for many causes. Your logcat didn't give any clue to them..

If you don't mind, post information in your question in a way, that I can reproduce the error

Comment: the best option is to use for example Postman and see what's the problem with server. 500 is server error (for example you misspelled variable in your server code)